# NodeJS Express Route returning asynchronous data in a rendered route

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous, pug

I'm trying to make some of my rendered pages smarter by passing some asynchronous functions into the rendering, like this:

```
var functions = {
    paginatedCategory: function(category) {
      db.query(`SELECT * FROM content WHERE FIND_IN_SET(Category, "${category}") ORDER BY position`, function(error, results) {
        console.log(results, 'results');
        return results;
      })
    }
}
```

Then in the route I'm doing this:

```
res.render('category', functions);
```

And in the `category.pug` page I'm calling that function inside like this:

```
ul
    each val in paginatedCategory('Products')
        li=val
```

In the console it's outputting all of the correct items in that category, however the render renders nothing, I'm guessing it's because the MySQL database query is asynchronous so it renders the page before it pulls all the items, how would you handle a situation like this?

Also I want to be able to pass parameters in directly from the `.pug` file because it will change from file to file.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the way you handle this is to get all your async data first, put it into a data structure and once you have all that data, then you call `res.render()` and pass it the data you've collected.

You can see an example of this in this article: [Rendering a page after asynchronous operations](https://gist.github.com/joepie91/c0069ab0e0da40cc7b54b8c2203befe1#rendering-a-page-after-asynchronous-operations).

Comment: If its a considerable amount of data the load being to become a problem, did you know another approach?

Comment: @Walter - I'd suggest you ask your own question with a lot more specific details and maybe we can help.